# How to write Euro (€) symbol to an Android PDF

Tags: android, pdf

I am creating a pdf from my android app but it is impossible to output the "€" symbol (it appears as "?")

I have already tried with the unicode value "\u20ac" and it is not working.
Any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to figure out what the char code is for the particular font you're using in your pdf.

Comment: Some characters don't exist in certain fonts - try a different font?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, first I was using "ISO 8859-1" which then I found it doesn't have the "€" char but now I am using "ISO 8859-15" which should work, but it still doesn't :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with APW (Android PDF Writer). Normally with ISO-8859-15 the EURO SIGN (U+20AC) is at position 164 (`0xa4`) but it gave me the currency sign (¤), so I tried with the position 128 (`0x80`) (`&#x80;` in my `string.xml`) used in Windows-1252 and it worked.

I suppose it's related to the PDF font encoding using `StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING`.